# No route to host

Tags: networking, routing

The host is reachable:

```
$ tracepath -n 172.20.192.12
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  172.16.91.1                                          21.104ms 
 1:  172.16.91.1                                          14.052ms 
 2:  172.16.1.6                                           14.974ms 
 3:  172.20.0.6                                           15.951ms 
 4:  172.20.192.12                                        23.078ms !H
     Resume: pmtu 1500
```

But check this:

```
$ wget https://jenkins.mycompany.intranet/
--2020-03-26 15:19:14--  https://jenkins.mycompany.intranet/
Resolving jenkins.mycompany.intranet (jenkins.mycompany.intranet)... 172.20.192.12
Connecting to jenkins.mycompany.intranet (jenkins.mycompany.intranet)|172.20.192.12|:443... failed: No route to host.
```

The browser can also not reach the host. It replies with:

```
This site can’t be reached 
(ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE)
```

Also:

```
$ telnet 172.20.192.12
Trying 172.20.192.12...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

What is this about?

Comment: `tracepath` actually tells that it is not reachable, as indicated by the `!H`.

Comment: While not relevant to your question, `TelNet` should never be used as there are no secure means of doing so since it does not support encryption of any kind, and, as such, is a massive security risk.  Any device supporting `TelNet` should also support `SSH`, which is encrypted by default and is the recommended remote access protocol.